# How to set selected item of ListView without scrolling the view

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1

The built in scroll when selected behaviour is annoying with items longer than screen height.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? can you elaborate more

Comment: Lets image a situation where at to top of the list I can see see the very bottom part of the first visible list item. I then click this bottom part of the item. I would like the item just get selected but the view gets undesirably scrolled up so that i can no longer see the bottom part of the item I just clicked; only the top of the item.